# targetSdkVersion no compatible

Tags: android

me esta mostrando un mensaje en targetSdkVersion mi ingles en nulo y la traducción no me soluciona mucho.

El proyecto tiene dos Módulos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me podéis decir como solucionarlo?

No se si en el apartado dependencies tengo que añadir alguna librería más, y de ser así, como me muestra unas cuantas, que librería tendría que añadir.

Gracias.

Comment: Si actualizaste Android Studio a su última versión simplemente tienes que borrar la linea respectiva a `targetSdkVersion` ya que no es necesaria.

Comment: Gracias  A. Cedano esta actualizado he desactivado linea //targetSdkVersion y ya no muestra el mensaje. Queria empezar por ahi porque he visto que en AndroidManifest.xml me muestra un error y pensaba que estaba relacionado, voy a poner un post para preguntarlo, por cierto, como te puedo puntuar que no me muestra ninguna opción.

Comment: Cuando pueda escribiré una respuesta documentada, entonces podrás puntuar.

Comment: Una respuesta documentada ? no se muy bien a que se refiere, cuando creo el primer post planteando el problema lo hago igual que en otros post, y en otros si que veo que las respuestas que dan las puedo puntuar.

Comment: Cuando digo *documentada* quiero decir, indicar yo, en mi respuesta, el origen del problema, citando la documentación de Android. No se refiere a tu pregunta, sino a una posible respuesta. Hace poco tuve un problema parecido, pero mi error lo que decía era que en la nueva versión de Android Studio lo calculaba de forma automática... estoy buscando alguna información sobre eso y no lo encuentro.

Comment: Gracias A. Cedano, como dice que ya no hace falta poner ese linea de código la he borrado y ya no me muestra esos mensajes, voy a seguir resolviendo los errores que me siguen saliendo en otros post, que me tiene frito el Android Studio, jeje.

Answer (score 1):

Te adjunto información de Google, donde indica que a partir del 1 de noviembre hay que mandar las actualizaciones con una targetSdkVersion >=26.

Hello Google Play Developer,

This is a reminder that starting November 1, 2018, updates to apps and games on Google Play will be required to target Android Oreo (API level 26) or higher. After this date, the Play Console will prevent you from submitting new APKs with a targetSdkVersion less than 26.

Configuring your app to target a recent API level ensures that users benefit from significant security and performance improvements, while still allowing your app to run on older Android versions (down to the minSdkVersion).

Action required

Please ensure that your apps are configured to target at least Android 8.0 (API level 26) by November 1, 2018. For technical advice on how to change your app's target API level to meet these requirements, refer to the migration guide.

Affected apps

The apps included below have one or more APKs—in production or testing tracks—that aren't currently targeting API level 26 or higher. Apps are listed with the maximum version code and corresponding targetSdkVersion. If you have more than 20 apps that could be affected in your account, please check the Play Console for a full list.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución pero sería buena idea nos ayudes a traducir esta información. De que forma ayudaría esto a resolver el problema del OP, revisar [answer]

Comment: Hola Las Perseidas, ahora tengo puesto targetSdkVersion 27, pero como ha comentado A. Cedano ya no es necesaria, aunque entiendo por la traducción que hace Google del texto que has puesto que sería necesaria para subir las aplicaciones a Google Play, en mi caso solo estoy haciendo una aplicación y no veo la forma de terminarla, y no quiero hacer más, jeje, si algún día con vuestra ayuda la consigo terminar es una aplicación personal, no la voy a subir a ningún lado.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad Android Studio sugiere usar las ùltimas versiones de las library, pero en este caso el mensaje se muestra se debe a que ya que usando:

`buildToolsVersion` 26.0.3

pero tienes un `targetSdkVersion` 25

por lo tanto lo conveniente es usar al menos un `targetSdkVersion` 26 que sería similar a el `buildToolsVersion`